# Parameter check ( $select ) implementation for API call

Tags: api, aws-api-gateway

I need to implement a rule for an API that if and only if parameter $select ( with at-least one column passed in it ) is passed in API call, user should get data else a message should be displayed about missing selection of column ( at least one ).

How to implement this, please guide ?

best regards,
MV

I am confused about where to start on this.